# How to hide the breadcrumb in ssrs report manager

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink

I have created a report and uploaded it in Report manager in SSRS. I have a asp.net web page where I have a hyperlink that has the URL to open the report in the report server. Now when the report opens user can see the report path on the breadcrumb. My question is how to hide that? My hyperlink is 
/ReportsDev/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fCFM%2fCurrentGeneralLedger%2fInterestCharges')">

I have tried &rv:Toolbar=false after the link but didn't work.

I cannot change style as suggested in a link by going 
:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ ReportManager as I don't have permission.

Any suggestion will be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i do to hide breadcrumb is

instead of going to (default site)

```
http://servername/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx
```

and then navigating to the report

i go to

```
http://servername/ReportServer
```

Comment: I have tried that, but then I get HTTP not found error

Comment: in your case it could be http://servername/ReportDevServer or http://servername/ReportsDevServer

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to find the same answer and realised the below.

Considering the link:
`http://servername/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx`

If in the above scenario **"Reports"** is named something else for e.g. **"Reports_foobar"** then the equivalent for report viewer would be **"ReportServer_foobar"** as below:

Report aspx:
`http://servername/Reports_foobar/Pages/Report.aspx`

ReportViewer aspx: 
`http://servername/ReportServer_foobar/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx`